# Show Listview items in Group By Order

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, group-by

I am developing a sms application. When sms received it is saved in sqlite db and is shown in the listview as listview item. Now what the problem is that "If 4 messages are received from the number lets says "090071222" then each time sms is saved in database and it is shown as 4 separate items in the listview. I want to make that only one item similar to text messaging apps. In other way i want to save all these 4 items in database but only want to show the latest sms received from that number in the listview. Only the latest sms out of 4 messages is shown on listview and when i tap on the list item then it should show 4 messages inside it.

Some one answered me that i can use Group By query to only show one sms from one phone number in my main list view but i am little bit confused that where to put that query.
This is  my class in which i am creating table for receiving sms.

```
public class DBtableforNotSpam extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBtableforNotSpam(Context context) {
super(context, "dbnotspam.db", null,
    1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  try {
        db.execSQL(Constants.query_createSMSTablee);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

Constants.query_createSMSTablee is defined here:

```
public static final String query_createSMSTablee = "create table " + "smss" + "(" + "id" + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
      + "contactnumber" + " text, " + "contactname" + " text," + "message" + " text," + "date" + " text)";
```

When any sms received i am saving it here in this method:

```
screenMessagee(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
```

This method is defined here:

```
public void screenMessagee(Context context, String msg_from, String msgSender,
    String msgBody, String msgDate) {
    DBtableforNotSpam smsdb = new DBtableforNotSpam(context);
    SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsdb.getWritableDatabase();

    String query_insertSMS = "insert into " + "smss" + "(" + "contactnumber" + "," + "contactname" + "," + "message"
        + "," + "date" + ") values (\"" + msg_from.toString() + "\", \"" + msgSender + "\",\"" + msgBody
        + "\",\"" + msgDate + "\")";

    dbw.execSQL(query_insertSMS);
    smsdb.close();
    dbw.close();
    abortBroadcast();

  }
```

When fetching the records in my main Listview i am doing this:

```
public ArrayList<Sms> fetchScreenedSms() {
ArrayList<Sms> smsInbox = new ArrayList<Sms>();
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from " + "smss" + ";";
DBtableforNotSpam smsD = new DBtableforNotSpam(this);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsD.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbw.rawQuery(query_fetchSMS, null);
if (cursor != null) {
  cursor.moveToLast();
  if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    do {

      Sms message = new Sms();
      message.id = cursor.getInt(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("id"));
      message.messageNumber = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("contactnumber"));
      message.messageSender = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("contactname"));
      message.messageContent = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("message"));
      message.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex("date")));
      smsInbox.add(message);
    } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
  } else {
     empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Please tell me where to put GROUB BY phonenumber Query so that only one sms show per phonenumber in my main listview. 
I tried writing GROUP BY in fetchScreenSms method but nothing is showing in my listview if GROUP BY Query is used. Maybe because i donot have a separate column for phonenumber. Please Help

Comment: You need to use an expandable list view. And the proper syntax of the query belongs into your earlier question.

Comment: any little code help?

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` clause is not all you need. You should tell the database, what you're interested in inside these groups.

You could try that, for me it worked:

`select max(id) from smss group by contactnumber`

**UPDATE**
I copy-pasted my updated query to my editor and got results. The query looks like in the comments:

`select message from smss where id in (select max(id) from smss group by contactnumber)`

**but** what I changed is the name of your last column. The name of your column is `date`, but `date` is also a data type.

First table shows all rows in the table, the second shows what is returned by the nested query.

[image: Result of the query]

Comment: If i have 5 messages in my database in which 3 messages are from this number "9922737" and 2 messages are from this number "63525252" then can you write the query for it so that only 1 1 sms show from these numbers in main listview

Comment: @ArslanAli If you just want to have the message, this (even if it's not beautiful) should work: `select message from smss where id in (select max(id) from smss group by contactnumber)`

Comment: Ok let me try i am confused because of max(id) that what to write in it

Comment: not working, this query doesnot show any item in my listview. My listview is showing nothing when this applied

Comment: Ok sir let me try, Thanks for your help though

Comment: It still not showing anything in my listview if i applied group by contactnumber
i change date to datum and applied ur query but it hasnt work :(

Comment: @ArslanAli I'd suggest that you debug your project to see where you 'lose' your data. I assume that you lose them after you got them from the database. Check if you reach this if-block after ` if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {...}` and what data is in the cursor.

Comment: Sure sir i am going to debug this

Answer (score 0):

Try following line

```
String query_fetchSMS = "select * from smss where id in (select max(id) from smss group by contactnumber);";
```

Comment: not working, this query doesnot show any item in my listview. My listview is showing nothing when this applied